# How to resize the Textview added dynamically to layout

Tags: android, textview

I trying to resize the text size of the textview which I have added to the layout dynmically.
The textview which is seen in the [picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_aS52bbVItGaUpsV3JxRXJYY2c/edit?usp=sharing) is added dynamically, I have set the text, text-size and color before adding the textview. But am wondering how can I change the textview's text-size after the textview is added to the layout. I am wondering can something like a pop-up menu be opened when the text view is long pressed. Please guide me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can call your_textview.setTextSize(size).

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this `your_textView.setTextSize(12)`.

To add a long click listener do like this

```
your_textView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // your code here
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

user Layout Parameters

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, height)
        tv.setLayoutParams(prams);
```